# How to sum 2 line in VBA with conditions

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a hard problem that I can't resolve in VBA.
I explain you with a simple example :

[image: database]

I have this database in excel.
my aim is to sum value of apple and apple_1 for column 1,2,3  but for column 4, I want put 1  IFI have just one value who is 1 and 0 IF the 2 value ( apple and apple_1) are 0.

of course, I can have sometimes apple_2 apple_3 apple_4 ...  ( I just take an easy example)

Here an example of what I want with VBA :

[image: final_result]

Comment: Could you please clarify the if clause? Is it a "or" condition? I mean, if there is at least one "1" in apples, column four should be 1, else should be zero.

Comment: You tagged the question with VBA so please post the code you've tried, where are you stuck and what errors are you getting.

Comment: @FernandoBarbosa looks more like an `XOR` condition to me. The question is how would that if condition look like if `apple_2`, `apple_3`, `apple_4` exist. That needs to be defined first.

Comment: for condition if, it means that :    only for columns that I want sum ( here it is apple and apple_1) , I take the value 1 if one of 2 ID ( apple apple_1) are 1 or 0 if the 2 ID are 0

Comment: I tried to recover the last carachters after I see a " _" and I I rename in ""

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code. It uses a dictionary and array and due to that it should be fast enough eve for larger ranges:

```
Sub testProcessFruits()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arr_, arrIt, arrFin
 Dim j As Long, i As Long, dict As Object
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 arr = sh.Range("A1:E" & lastR).Value2
 
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
    If InStr(arr(i, 1), "_") > 0 Then
        arr_ = Split(arr(i, 1), "_")
        If Not dict.Exists(arr_(0)) Then
            dict.Add arr_(0), Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3), arr(i, 4))
        Else
            arrIt = dict(arr_(0))
            For j = 0 To UBound(arrIt) - 1
                arrIt(j) = arrIt(j) + arr(i, j + 2)
            Next j
            dict(arr_(0)) = arrIt
        End If
    Else
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3), arr(i, 4))
        Else
            arrIt = dict(arr(i, 1))
            For j = 0 To UBound(arrIt) - 1
                arrIt(j) = arrIt(j) + arr(i, j + 1)
            Next j
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrIt
        End If
    End If
 Next i

 ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count, 1 To 4)
 For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    arrFin(i + 1, 1) = dict.Keys()(i)
    arrFin(i + 1, 2) = dict.Items()(i)(0)
    arrFin(i + 1, 3) = dict.Items()(i)(1)
    arrFin(i + 1, 4) = dict.Items()(i)(2)
 Next i
 With sh.Range("H1")
    .Resize(1, 4).Value2 = sh.Range("A1:D1").Value2
    .Offset(1).Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value2 = arrFin
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: awesome, thanks you !! I try now and I comeback to you in few minutes

Comment: @jacques Please, test it after a minute. The version I posted needs a reference, but I will adapt it to  not be needed, anymore.

Comment: @jacques OK, updated. I needed `Scripting` to easily debug it during testing...

Comment: Ok no problem, just is it normal thing that it put me error here : dict As New Scripting.Dictionary       to be honest, I learned VBA few day ago, and I like it but your code seem to be very awesome, I will try unterstand alone, but maybe I would like if I could have your help to unterstand

Comment: I tried your code, and I have 2 problem, first, I don't have my column 4, she dissaspears and after, I would like to crush old dataframe per the new, so in your code, I replace H1 per A1 but it doesn't give me exactely what I want,  thanks in advance for what you did, it's so hard and awesome

Comment: @jacques I am afraid I cannot get you... Of course `Column 4` disappeared? You said **"for column 1,2,3 but for column 4"**. In fact, being different numbers in it and you do not want adding them, in the processed range **which has less rows** what value to be kept? Like you said, they may be more 'apple_1, apple_2, apple_10'... What to place the code in that column? If you change H1 with A1, you will overwrite rows which does not match that column. The processed result must be returned somewhere else. If you set a rule/algorithm to choose something for that column, I can adapt the code...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245036/discussion-between-jacques-and-faneduru).

Comment: @jacques But I will leave my office in about half an hour and if you come back with the logic to choose the 'Column 4', in this period, I can try something. Anyhow, your example is wrong. It should contain more than two cases, in order to, at least, deduce what is to be done... I did not understand anything from what you tried describing.

Comment: @jacques Still alive?